# Replacing Variables with Microsoft C#

Tags: c#

Can't get "z" to be replaced by the code below. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

```
//Generate Nut Part Number
textBox7.Text = "MLA028Z-CAN-" + comboBox2.Text + "R" + "-" + comboBox3.Text + "z" + "0";

//Replaces z Variable in Lead Screw Assembly Part Number
if (comboBox1.Text == "0")
    textBox6.Text.Replace("z", "B");
else if (comboBox1.Text == "1")
    textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
else if (comboBox1.Text == "2")
    textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
else if (comboBox1.Text == "3")
    textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
else if (comboBox1.Text == "4")
    textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
else if (comboBox1.Text == "5")
    textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
else if (comboBox1.Text == "6")
    textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
else if (comboBox1.Text == "7")
    textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "B");
```

Comment: `String.Replace()` doesn't mutate the string. It creates and returns a new string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify each of your

```
textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
```

with

```
textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is `Replace()` returns a new `string` with the replacement made. It does not update the `string` on which it operates, and so you have to do that yourself:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "0") textBox6.Text = textBox6.Text.Replace("z", "B");
```

Making that change (i.e. assigning the result back to `textBox6.Text`/`textBox7.Text`) will make your code work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`String`s are immutable in .NET, hence `textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D")`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not really using the value assign to the textbox in the first place and only have two different scenarios in your if's I've rearranged the code a bit. The main problem however as stated elsewhere is that you weren't assigning the result of the replace back to the text property

```
 //Replaces z Variable in Lead Screw Assembly Part Number
 var replace = "z";
 int combo;
 if(int.TryParse(comboBox1.Text, out combo)){ 
    if (combo == 0) textBox6.Text = textBox6.Text.Replace("z", "B");
    else if (combo >0 && combo < 7) replace = "D";
    else if (combo == 7) replace = "B";
 }
//Generate Nut Part Number
 textBox7.Text = "MLA028Z-CAN-" + comboBox2.Text + "R" + "-" + comboBox3.Text + replace + "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the main question but i would also recomend replacing all those else if with the following.

```
var oneToSix = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Select(x => x.ToString());
if (comboBox1.Text == "0") textBox6.Text = textBox6.Text.Replace("z", "B");
if (comboBox1.Text == "7") textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "B");
else if (oneToSix.Contains(comboBox1.Text)) textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
```

Answer (score -2):

as an aside, this should be a switch statement:

```
switch(comboBox1.Text){
    case "0":
        textBox6.Text = textBox6.Text.Replace("z", "B");
        break;
    case "7":
        textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "B");
        break;
    case "1":
    case "2":
    case "3":
    case "4":
    case "5":
    case "6":
         textBox7.Text = textBox7.Text.Replace("z", "D");
         break;
}
```

Comment: how the heck do you figure?!? he's got 8 evaluations of the same object in chained "else if's".  A greater case for a switch statement does not exist.

Comment: Except there's only really two scenarios

Comment: Especially then... this seems ideal for a switch. the cases for the many can fall through.

Comment: @Rune look again, there are 3 ;-)

Comment: @Jeremy look at my answer no fall throughs but as Ben points out there's three case not two as I said

Comment: @Ben yeah I missed the textbox6 as you probably had guessed

Comment: @Rune Yeah i also missed it at first.

Comment: Well, it seems we have a difference of opinion.  I definitely think the switch is much easier to read and understand what is going on in the code that a bunch of parsed else-if's.  I certainly don't think my answer should have been downvoted for it but oh well.

Comment: @Jeremy I didn't downvote but personally can't remember when I last wrote a switch. There never seems to be a perfect oppurtunity for it but then I very rarely have more than and if-else. That aside you have an error in your example though. The same ben spotted in my first comment. 0 and 7 are different in OPs code